# Is there a way to get a tuple's data when using recursion?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, tuples, maze

I'm solving a maze problem with recursion. The x,y coordinates are represented as tuples. When I call the function recursively, it tries to retrieve the data from the tuple, the int value in current_row becomes unsubscriptable as reported in my TypeError. Is there a way to perhaps store the data from the tuple differently so that it can be updated every recursive call?

```
maze = [[0, 1], [0, 0]]

def solve(m, cl, e):
    # m - maze (list of lists)
    # cl - current location
    # e  - exit

    current_row = cl[0]
    current_col = cl[1]
    
    # position marker
    m[current_row][current_col] = "P"

    # base cases
    if m == []:
        return False
    
    # hits a wall, returns false
    if m[cl[0]][cl[1]] == 1:
        return False
    
    # found end of maze
    if cl == e:
        return True
    
    # recursive cases        
    if solve(m, m[cl[0] + 1][cl[1]], e) or solve(m, m[cl[0]][cl[1] - 1], e) or solve(m, m[cl[0] - 1][cl[1]], e) or solve(m, m[cl[0]][cl[1] + 1], e):
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(solve(maze, (0,0), (1,1)))
```

Comment: `s` is not defined in this code.

Comment: In your recursive cases, you are passing the value of m at a position (an integer), not the position itself (a tuple).

Answer (score 0):

The code shown doesn't define `s` and doesn't call the recursive cases with a tuple for the starting position `cl`, but instead passes the value of the maze at that position (an integer or a `P`) and is why later recursive calls fail.  Integers are unsubscriptable.

Some other logic errors is handling traversing off the boundaries of the array and removing the `'P'` when backtracking.

Here's working code with corrections using integers of 0 (potential path), 1 (wall), 2 (current path):

```py
# build a boundary wall and potential paths from start (1,1) to end (7,7)
maze = [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1],
        [1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1],
        [1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1],
        [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1],
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]

def solve(m, s, e):
    # m - maze (list of lists)
    # s - current location
    # e  - exit

    x,y = s
    
    # not a potential path, returns false
    if m[x][y] != 0:
        return False

    # mark as current path
    m[x][y] = 2

    # found end of maze
    if s == e:
        return True
    
    # recursive cases, check down, left, up, right (following right wall)
    if solve(m, (x+1,y), e) or solve(m, (x,y-1), e) or solve(m, (x-1, y), e) or solve(m, (x, y+1), e):
        return True
    else:
        # backtrack
        m[x][y] = 0
        return False

if solve(maze, (1,1), (7,7)):  # True if solution exists
    for row in maze:
        # translate each row into a nicer graphic
        print(''.join(' █X'[n] for n in row))
```

Output:

```
█████████
█XXXXX  █
█ ███X█ █
█   █X█ █
█ ███X█ █
█   █X█ █
█ ███X███
█   █XXX█
█████████
```